# DIV tag not following height

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I have a header, which is made up of an image on the left, and some text on the right. The text is made up of two parts: line one (top) and line two (bottom). Now both of these need to occupy 50% of the height of the header. But as the height has no set height, they are not changing.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/olivermurfett/pamkeov5/

Perhaps adding `height: auto;` might help.

UPDATE 1:
Illisation of desired outcome:
[image: Header]
<sub>(source: [catholic.edu.au](http://www.shckyneton.catholic.edu.au/_sharedimg/header.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: how to make the rows actually fit the header with width 50%; @AhsN

Comment: @OliverMurfett what you actually want to do yet not clear with you question

Comment: check the jsfiddle, and the divs that the text is in should occupy 50% height, of the header

Comment: I think it is difficult to illustrate your point without updating the image URL - put an image with the same dimensions from https://placehold.it/ so we can have a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: It looks like a pretty fixed header.  What is the problem with setting the height of `#header` which would then fix your problem? (after you removed an erroneous semicolon)

Comment: Check this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pamkeov5/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
#header-text-container {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
}
#text-SACRED-HEART-COLLEGE {
    float:left;
    font-size: 25px;
}
#text-A-Vibrant-Life {
    float:right;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#text-KYNETON {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pamkeov5/7/)

Comment: Thats not what im looking for.. @Ahs N

Comment: @OliverMurfett Can u provide an illustration of what you are trying to achieve then?

Comment: the image has been provide

Comment: @OliverMurfett Updated JSFiddle again :)

Comment: Whats missing then? Wasn't the floating the solution?

Comment: @Haudegen Yes, the floating was the solution. I updated the JSFiddle altering the appearance to make it look close to the image provided (colors, font size and things like that)

Comment: @AhsN Yes, I am just wondering why you didn't get the best-Answer-Tick ... ;-)